# What is the best way to pass gradle properties from bamboo?

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, bamboo, gradlew

As per [Gradle Documentation for Build Environment](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) you can see there are several ways to do this.

One important constraint is that I can't check in these properties into VCS.

Additionally clarifying that these are project properties.

I am invoking `gradlew` as a `bash` command on `Bamboo`

Various ways

1. Set `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable
2. Set `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable
3. Pass -D to `gradlew` but this don't seem to work for some reason
4. Any other better ways...

It is best to know the pitfalls upfront hence posting it here for your answers.

I want to pass these as System properties that my unit tests can use and sometimes as project properties.

Comment: Usually `-P` or checkin a `gradle.properties.ci` and copy it to `gradle.properties` prior to building. I prefer the latter approach unless I have per-job customizations.

Comment: You should clarify whether you want to pass in project properties or system properties. `-D` should work fine for system properties.

Comment: @PeterLadbrook I have clarified the questions as per your suggestion